# How can i write a fraction for a UILabel in interface builder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

On the left: current
On the right: this is what I need

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are directly setting the value in Interface builder. You can simply copy this (⅓) and paste in there and adjust the font size.

If you are setting from the code, You have unicode characters for defined fractions. You can use them.

For Example, for 1/3,

```
const unichar third = 0x2153;
labelText = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&third length:1];
```

For other fractions, check this [link](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2150.pdf)